# Realtek USB GBE Family Controller Suddenly Dropped Speed

Tags: networking

I'm on Spectrum 100 Mbps Internet. I've been getting speeds of 100-130 Mbps until last night all of a sudden my speed tests are ALL 50 Mbps and lower. I've checked all the cables, updated the drivers, powered down the laptop, the router and the switch, disconnected the power cord from the socket, waited 15 mins, plugged them back in, retested and get the same results. The times I've had this problem before (6 months ago and longer) this would always work and my speeds would go back to normal so I can't figure out why it is not working now.

I made sure SPEED & DUPLEX are set to 1.0 Gbps FULL DUPLEX. POWER MANAGEMENT is disabled and so is ENERGY EFFICIENT. I also checked under Network Connections>Local Area Network>Status>Speed is showing as 1.0 Gbps.

I don't know what else to check.

The only thing I have done recently is I installed Kaspersky Total Security 2019 as my license for the 2018 version was set to expire.

Not sure you need it but here are my specs:
HP Pavilion Sleekbook 15-b119wm, Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit, Wired Juiced Systems 6+1+1 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet Hub, Realtek USB GbE Family Controller, TRENDnet TEG-S81g 8-Port Gigabit GREENnet Switch, 1.6GHz AMD Quad-Core A8-4555M Accelerated Processor, 7.47 GB RAM Crucial 8GB (2X4GB) PC3-12800 1600MHZ DDR3 204PIN SODIMM 1.35v CL11 Unbuff, ASUS USB 2.0 6X External Slim Blu-Ray Re-writer Combo SBC-06D2X-U-BL w BDXL, DELL P2414H Monitor, 65W AC adapter

Comment: Check your modem/router line stats

Comment: Why do you think the network adapter is to blame? It is much more likely the problem is with the access device or its uplink connection.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I just assumed it was the network adapter as that is what fixed it before when I had this issue.

Comment: I checked the modem log and the last thing logged was on Oct 30 and it wasn't relevant to speed issues

Comment: Reboot your cable modem.

Comment: Thank you Spiff, I rebooted the modem, the router, the Switch and the laptop to no avail, even unplugged each one and waited 15 minutes before plugging them back in.